# How can I check if a certificate is self-signed?

Tags: c#, .net, certificate, self-signed, x509certificate2

I'm using C#.NET and need to install a bunch of certificates into the Windows certificate store.

I need to check which of those certificates are root certificates (i.e. self-signed), so I can install them into the "Trusted root certificates" store.

I'm using the standard `X509Certificate2` class. My current idea is to check whether the `Issuer` and `Subject` are the same.

I've noticed that [`X509Certificate2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has `Issuer` - `IssuerName` and `Subject` - `SubjectName`.

Is it better to compare `Issuer` to `Subject`, or `IssuerName` to `SubjectName`? Or doesn't it really matter?

Also, is this a reliable method or would I be better off using another approach?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

See this post: [java - Find if a certificate is self signed or CA signed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10309119/563532)

While it's not C#, the comment from the solution notes

> If the subject and issuer are the same, it is self-signed

means you're correct about the way you're trying to validate it.

`IssuerName` and `SubjectName` return a `DistinguishedName` which contains `RawData` (a `byte[]` containing the raw information for the issuer/subject). You'd be best off comparing this field, though I *believe* comparing `Subject` and `Issuer` is just as valid.

So, you could write something like this:

```
public static bool IsSelfSigned(X509Certificate2 cert)
{
    return cert.SubjectName.RawData.SequenceEqual(cert.IssuerName.RawData);
}
```

Comment: That's just convention and in no way verifies that the certificate actually is self-signed.