# Verify x509 certificate with openssl to be valid and signed by trusted CAs

Tags: openssl, x509certificate

In a shell script I want to verify a x509 certificate with openssl to be sure that it is valid and signed by one of my root CAs. I tried this:

```
openssl verify -CAfile /path/to/CAfile mycert.pem
```

It works but for a self signed certificate I get the output:

```
error 18 at 0 depth lookup:self signed certificate
OK
```

The error is shown but it ends with OK and the status code is 0 so I don't get an error in my script.

I could parse the output but that's not a robust code for a secure production environment.

I need a command that yields an error on self signed certificates.

EDIT

```
% openssl version 
OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
% cat /etc/redhat-release 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.9 (Maipo)
```

works with openssl 1.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your code, a dummy CA and a dummy self-signed cert I cannot replicate your results. Please update your example or include the openssl version.

Last output line is `error: mycert.pem: verification failed` and the return code is 2 (`echo $?`) as opposed to the OK message with a 0 return code. I also get the error 18 self-signed message you received. I am using openssl 1.1.1i.

Error 18 is in fact, a robust error code and is documented in the openssl verify man page as the code specifically for self signed certificates.